# Find $E(X_1|X_2\leq x_2, X_3\leq x_3)$ where $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is multivariate normal

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $(X_1\; X_2\; X_3)^{T} \sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$. We want to find $E(X_1|X_2\leq x_2, X_3\leq x_3)$. In my course we are taught conditional expectation in a rigorous way unlike I previously knew. So I understand the meaning of $E(X_1|X_2,X_3)$ but I don't understand the expression given above. I tried to solve this with brute force but I couldn't do it. I have found the conditional probability distribution to be $$F(X_1\le x|X_2\le x_2,X_3\le x_3)=\dfrac{\int_{-\infty}^{x_3}\int_{-\infty}^{x_2}\int_{-\infty}^{x}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{\mu})^{T}\Sigma^{-1/2}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{\mu})\right)\;\mathrm{d}y_1\mathrm{d}y_2\mathrm{d}y_3}{\int_{-\infty}^{x_3}\int_{-\infty}^{x_2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{\mu})^{T}\Sigma^{-1/2}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{\mu})\right)\;\mathrm{d}y_1\mathrm{d}y_2\mathrm{d}y_3}$$
Here we take $y=(y_1\; y_2 \; y_3)^{T}$. Can someone help me out?

Comment: This is a so-called trivial conditioning, since the event $A=\{X_2\le x_2,X_3\le x_3\}$ has positive probability, hence the détour by the conditional CDF is not useful, simply write $E(X_1|A)=E(X_1;A)/P(A)$ with $$E(X_1;A)=c\int_{-\infty}^{x_3}\int_{-\infty}^{x_2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} y_{1}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(y-\mu)^{T}\Sigma^{-1/2}(y-\mu)\right)\;\mathrm{d}y_1\mathrm{d}y_2\mathrm{d}y_3$$ and $$P(A)=c\int_{-\infty}^{x_3}\int_{-\infty}^{x_2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(y-\mu)^{T}\Sigma^{-1/2}(y-\mu)\right)\;\mathrm{d}y_1\mathrm{d}y_2\mathrm{d}y_3$$

Comment: ...  for some constant $c$ whose value is irrelevant.

Comment: @Did Thank you for replying. I have done that, but I can't do the integration, that's why I posted it. I would be happy if you help me out.

Comment: With this degree of generality (parameters $\mu$, $\Sigma$, $x_2$, $x_3$...), I am not sure much can be said. Sure you do not have a more specific problem in mind?

Comment: @Did Sadly, no. The problem was given for the general case.